# Get the day of the month (not using .NET DateTime)

Tags: c#

I'm working on a date-time system for a game. In the interest of reusability, I decided not to use the DateTime included in .NET. It reflects Earth time, whereas I'd like to be able to have arbitrary values for things like hoursPerDay, and have, say, 10 months in a year, with any number of days each. For now I don't care about things like leap years, or time zones.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the current day of the month (MM-**DD**-YYYY). The code in question is the DayOfMonth property's *get* method.

```
public sealed class Time
    {
        int _ticks = 0;
        int _ticksPerSecond = 30;
        int _secondsPerMinute = 60;
        int _minutesPerHour = 60;
        int _hoursPerDay = 24;
        readonly List<string> _days;
        readonly Dictionary<string, int> _months;

        // I haven't decided on ctor parameters yet, but we'd define base units
        public Time()
        {
            // What we call the days of the week.
            _days = new List<string> { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday" };

            // What we call the months of the year, and the number of days each.
            _months = new Dictionary<string, int>
                          {
                              {"January", 31},
                              {"February", 28},
                              {"March", 31}
                          };
        }

        public void Advance(int ticks)
        {
            _ticks += ticks;
        }

        // Number of ticks elapsed since epoch start
        public int TotalTicks { get { return _ticks; } }
        // Number of ticks elapsed during the current second
        public int CurrentTicks { get { return _ticks % _ticksPerSecond; } }

        public int TotalSeconds { get { return _ticks / _ticksPerSecond; } }
        public int CurrentSeconds { get { return TotalSeconds % _secondsPerMinute; } }

        public int TotalMinutes { get { return TotalSeconds / _secondsPerMinute; } }
        public int CurrentMinutes { get { return TotalMinutes % _minutesPerHour; } }

        public int TotalHours { get { return TotalMinutes / _minutesPerHour; } }
        public int CurrentHours { get { return TotalHours % _hoursPerDay; } }

        public List<string> Days { get { return _days; } }
        public int TotalDays { get { return TotalHours / _hoursPerDay; } }
        public int CurrentDay { get { return TotalDays % _days.Count; } }
        public string DayOfWeek { get { return _days[CurrentDay]; } }
        public int DayOfMonth
        {
            get
            {
                var d = 0;
                while (d < TotalDays)
                {
                    foreach (var month in Months)
                    {
                        var daysInMonth = month.Value;
                        while (daysInMonth > 0 && d < TotalDays)
                        {
                            d++;
                            daysInMonth--;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return d;
            }
        }

        public Dictionary<string, int> Months { get { return _months; } }
        public int TotalMonths { get { return TotalDays / _months.Values.Sum(); } }
        public int CurrentMonth { get { return TotalMonths % Months.Count; } }
        …
    }
```

A. The code above doesn't work. It always returns a fixed value.

B. The only way I can think of to accomplish this is to iterate through each month, adding up days until we reach each month's day count, until we hit the total days elapsed. That doesn't seem very efficient to me, especially with the redundant checking `if (d < TotalDays)` above.

C. It seems like the more time that elapses, the longer it will take to find the DayOfMonth (and perhaps other) value(s).

I guess I'm looking for a paradigm shift, because I think I might be painting myself in a corner.

### Update

For anyone who is interested in the (somewhat) working algorithms, I got this fixed by changing the DayOfMonth property to the following.

```
public int DayOfMonth
{
    get
    {
        var d = TotalDays;
        var found = false;

        while(!found)
        {
            foreach (var month in _months)
            {
                if (d > month.Value) d -= month.Value;
                else
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return d;
    }
}
```

The TotalMonths property needed a similar fix.

```
public int TotalMonths
{
    get
    {
        var d = TotalDays;
        var found = false;
        var m = 0;

        while(!found)
        {
            foreach (var month in _months)
            {
                if (d > month.Value)
                {
                    d -= month.Value;
                    m++;
                }
                else
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return m;
    }
}
```

which enables MonthOfYear:

```
public string MonthOfYear { get { return _months.Keys.ToList()[CurrentMonth]; } }
```

So far things seem to be in order. I suspect there's a more elegant solution, perhaps involving Yield (which I don't yet understand), so if anyone comes up with something interesting I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: I wonder if a user can supply a custom `CalenderInfo` class in .NET? Interesting.

Comment: So sad that DateTime is only valid for Earth... Will that be the next Millennium bug???

Comment: @Guillaume: Why not, given the explicit lack of handling leap years?

Comment: You should probably separate out the "calendar system" part from the "one single instant" part, btw. You don't need each instant to have a complete list of months etc, do you?

Comment: @Jon My bad, read it too quickly ;)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: This would be a singleton; I just thought the extra code would be noise. Also, I'm plowing through your article on singletons before I decide how to do this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have leap years, it's relatively easy:

- You can work out how many ticks are in a year, and use the `%` operator to work out the tick within the year for a given value
- Divide by the number of ticks in a day to get the day within the year
- You could then have a statically-constructed array for the "start day-of-year of each month", do a binary search to find the right month, and then subtract the start day-of-year to find the day within the month. Alternatively, just iterate over the months and subtract the number of days in each month until you find your value is less than the number of days within the month you're considering.

One option: use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) and implement your own `CalendarSystem`... which probably isn't *too* hard, except for understanding the system to start with :) (Bear in mind that Noda Time isn't production-quality yet, but you could have fun with it...)

Comment: Also, you could use the same "start day-of-year of each month" array to find out the CurrentMonth. That code there looks strange and I doubt it will return the correct month unless all months have the same number of days.

Comment: @Radu094: I haven't looked at most of the code in the question, to be honest :)

Comment: You can get even simpler by making each month the same length. I have done this in a (pen and pencil) game and used the remaining days for a "Festival" period

Comment: I'll look into NodaTime, and your other suggestion. Thanks. I was hoping someone would post a "here, use this code you won't understand" and I could suss out the idea from that, but I get the sense that this is more complicated than I initially thought.

Comment: @Mike B: Yeah, I know that would simplify things enormously; I am partial to the idea of different numbers of days for each month, though.

Answer (score 3):

I've not used it myself in the past, but the [System.Globalization.Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.aspx) class may help you.

It looks as though you can create your own "calendars" for use with DateTime etc. Their example implementations include things like "ChineseLunisolarCalendar, so perhaps instead of doing all the hard work yourself, you can create some sort of "calendar specification" so you can still use the built-in types?

Comment: IIRC, `DateTime` will convert input into the Gregorian calendar even if you create it with a specific calendar system. It's a bit broken, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

this is how the `DateTime` does it when you look at the decompiled assembly:

```
private int GetDatePart(int part)
{
    long internalTicks = this.InternalTicks;
    int num1 = (int)internalTicks / 864000000000L;
    int num2 = num1 / 146097;
    num1 = num1 - (num2 * 146097);
    int num3 = num1 / 36524;
    if (num3 == 4)
    {
        num3 = 3;
    }
    num1 = num1 - (num3 * 36524);
    int num4 = num1 / 1461;
    num1 = num1 - (num4 * 1461);
    int num5 = num1 / 365;
    if (num5 == 4)
    {
        num5 = 3;
    }
    if (part == 0)
    {
        return ((((num2 * 400) + (num3 * 100)) + (num4 * 4)) + num5) + 1;
    }
    num1 = num1 - (num5 * 365);
    if (part == 1)
    {
        return num1 + 1;
    }
    bool flag = num5 == 3 && ((num4 == 24 && num3 == 3) || !(num4 == 24));
    int[] daysToMonth366 = DateTime.DaysToMonth366;
    int num6 = num1 >> 6;
    while (num1 >= daysToMonth366[num6])
    {
        num6++;
    }
    if (part == 2)
    {
        return num6;
    }
    return (num1 - daysToMonth366[(num6 - 1)]) + 1;
}



internal long InternalTicks
{
    get
    {
        return this.dateData & 4611686018427387903L;
    }
}



public int Day
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetDatePart(3);
    }
}
```